# JavaScript - Explanation of reduce example

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, immutability

Its my first question on StackOverflow (if i do something wrong - sorry!)

I have a reducer function where my teacher helped me, and i can really grasp what it means.
It's a todo app where i have a button. When pressing the button all items in the todo list should be marked as completed. When i press the button again, all items should be in-completed.

I get most of the code. The one part I cant graps my mind round is the explanation mark before the items array `!store.items.find`.
If anyone could give an explanation i would be thankful!
Also let me know if you need me to share more code.

```
completeAllTodo: (store, action) => {
    const areAllTasksCompleted = !store.items.find(todo => !todo.isComplete)
    if (areAllTasksCompleted) {
        const completedItems = store.items.map(todo => {
            return {
                ...todo,
                isComplete: false
            }
        })
        store.items = completedItems
    } else {
        const completedItems = store.items.map(todo => {
            return {
                ...todo,
                isComplete: true
            }
        })
        store.items = completedItems
    }
},
```

Comment: It casts `!"some val"` to a boolean, so if `find` returns a falsy value the result would be `false`

Comment: It has two `!` operators and converts an object to a boolean. It is extremely confusing. Use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this: `store.items.every(todo => todo.isComplete)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well

```
store.items.find(todo => !todo.isComplete)
```

means find any item who is not complete yet if there is no such an item then find will return undefined, and so

```
!store.items.find(todo => !todo.isComplete)
```

means if there is an item which is not completed then this will be false if all items are complete then find will return undefined and this whole expression will be true

a better way to express the same logic will be

```
const areAllTasksCompleted = store.items.every(todo => todo.isComplete)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `Array#find` will return an array of matching items if any otherwise returns `undefined`.

So, if there's some incomplete todos `find` will return an array and negating that array will result in `false`, and if there's no incomplete todos it will return `undefined` and negating `undefined` will result in `true`.

Consider the code snippets below:

```js
const todo = [
  { task: "Exercise", isComplete: true },
  { task: "Buy Grocery", isComplete: false },
];

// There is one incomplete todo in the above todo array
const resultFromFind = todo.find(t => !t.isComplete);
console.log(resultFromFind); // { task: 'Buy Grocery', isComplete: false }

const allComplete = !resultFromFind
console.log(allComplete) // false
```

```js
const todo = [
  { task: "Exercise", isComplete: true },
  { task: "Buy Grocery", isComplete: true },
];

// There is no incomplete todo in the above todo array
const resultFromFind = todo.find(t => !t.isComplete);
console.log(resultFromFind); // undefined

const allComplete = !resultFromFind
console.log(allComplete) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const areAllTasksCompleted = !store.items.find(todo => !todo.isComplete)
```

`store.items.find` returns the first item that matches criteria of the predicate callback.

`todo => !todo.isComplete` is your predicate callback, which is passed one argument (the current item in the iteration) and returns `true` if the item is not complete (or `false` if it is complete).

Therefore, this expression will return the value of the first element in the array that is not completed.

The `!` before the whole expression negates the result of the expression. In JavaScript, any object value will be coerced to `true`, and a `null` or `undefined` value will be coerced to `false`, so if the expression finds a value that matches the predicate, your const will be assigned to `false`, otherwise it will be `true`.